# Using serializer with foreign key model when creating new entry

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

At first, I had this serializer and it works well for `GET` and `POST`(create new entry)

```
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()
    detail = serializers.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','detail','drawing','user','created_at','updated_at')
```

in viewset where creating entry.

```
class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['user'] = request.user.id #set userid
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)    
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer) # it makes the new entry with user
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict,null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  
   
class Drawing(models.Model):
    drawing = f.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In this casel, `user` is foreign key model.

So I want to get the user's name,email and so on, then I changed `Serializer` like this.

```
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()
    detail = serializers.JSONField()
    user = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True) # change here
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','detail','drawing','user','created_at','updated_at')
```

It also works well for `get`. I can get the data from `CustomUser` Model as `user`.

however when `POST(creating)`, it shows the error

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Why does this happen and what is the user_id?

---

As @Utkucan Bıyıklı's answer.

I updated like this below,

However it doesn't show either `user_data` nor `user` in response. (I think `user` is correctly not shown though)

```
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()
    detail = serializers.JSONField()
    user_data = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True) # change here
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','detail','drawing','user','user_data', 'created_at','updated_at')
        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"write_only": True}}
```

Comment: when creating a new Drawing instance, the userID is not populated (required in constructor), and you need to first take values of user before passing it to the serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `ForeignKey` into your model, Django create `FKFIELD_id` field into the database. In your problem, you set `user` is `read_only` field. So you can not pass `user` field to serializer and you getting `database` error.

The easiest way is split `user` and `user_data`

```py
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()
    detail = serializers.JSONField()
    user_data = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True, source="user") # change here
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','detail','drawing','user','user_data', 'created_at','updated_at')
        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"write_only": True}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! BTW, I added `user_data`in serializer ,but `user_data` not appeared in Response.

Comment: Sorry i updated the code

Answer (score 1):

So what you have done here is called nested serializer, in that case, you used the `CustomUserSerializer` to serialize the `User` object to get its attributes this is what happens when you call the `GET` method.

But when you try and create a `Drawing` object by calling the `POST` method, **Django** blocks the `user` value even if you sent it in the request data, because you have defined `read_only=True`. and it brings out this error

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

which basically tells you that you have a field called `user` in the `Drawing` model - which is a foreign key - [it cannot be null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#:%7E:text=If%20True%20%2C%20Django%20will%20store,Default%20is%20False%20.), and I need the primary key of that model which is the `id` of the `user`.

---

**The first solution:**
Simply remove the `read_only=True`, and make sure to include the `user` field in your request data when creating a new `Drawing` object.

**The second solution:**
Create two different attributes in your serializer one is for reading and the other is for writing, for example:

```py
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()
    detail = serializers.JSONField()
    user_details = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user') # change here
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id', 'detail',' drawing', 'user', 'user_details', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"write_only": True}}
```

**The third solution:**
override the create method of the serializer and manually set the `user` field before saving the `Drawing` object. This allows you to keep the `user` field as `read-only` in the serializer but still provide a value when creating the object, for example:

```py
class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()
    detail = serializers.JSONField()
    user = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Drawing
        fields = ('id', 'detail', 'drawing', 'user', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        validated_data['user'] = user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: THank you for your detailed answer. In this case I use the second solution as @Utkucan Bıyıklı also suggested. Yout answer  gives me furthre understanding.

Comment: Happy to hear that!